# Does SEO improve from picture alt text that doesn't include keywords?

Tags: seo, alt-attribute

In [this article](https://yoast.com/image-seo/) it says that you always should describe the picture with your alt text. For example a picture of a nervous worker on a website dedicated to negotiating higher salaries within the workplace should be named "nervous worker shaking boss's hand".

But logic states that the alt text for that image should be "anxiety while negotiating salary" because that is descriptive and more keyword rich. However it is mentioned that including keywords actually hurts your ranking.... I don't get it?

How is describing a picture so specifically to the point you don't include a keyword help SEO?

Comment: The description should be what you want it to be. It helps image search if the alt text is specific. It should be conversational. Otherwise, generally speaking, the image alt tag does little to nothing for the page itself. Just image search. Cheers!!

Comment: The Alt tag came about for impaired users, not search engines... Write your alt tags for users, not search engines... that way, not only do you improve your user experience, Google will consider your alt tags more nature.

Comment: The alt text is to provide content for those who cannot see the image. It might because it didn't download or the user is blind and using a screen reader. So wite alt content to describe the image so users know what the image contains. Not for what keywords you want to rank for.

Comment: @SimonHayter beat me to it. :)

Comment: @JohnConde yep :)

Comment: @JohnConde what about the SEO implications for alt tags? Can't it both help impaired users while improving SEO?

Comment: @BarAkiva Keywords in ALT tag doesn't improve SEO... it is one signal of many that search engines can use to establish what the page is about, once a search engine establishes what your page is about, repeating the keyword over and over in various paragraphs, headers and images becomes ignored and holds no more weight the more you repeat it. Having a good page title, meta description and one or more paragraphs of text is all the information that these search engine crawlers need... The biggest weight of rankings comes from your domain authority and external signals.

Comment: I'll do a blog post shortly and show you a good example of a good alt tag.

Answer (score 1):

Google and Bing hijacked the ALT attribute and because of that many webmasters and SEO guru's have been using the ALT tag for rankings and not what it was originally designed for, that being impaired users or users that have images disabled in their browser (useful for people on narrowband).

Alt descriptions should consist of actual image contents and not the keywords of the page, unless the description of the image happens to naturally have a keyword appear in it.

*A few examples:*

1. An image of Man in Suit

   - Yes: A smart dressed man in a dark navy suit
   - No: <strike>A Professional Website Designer</strike>
2. An plain image with the words Web Design in it

   - Yes: Image with the written text Web Design
   - No: <strike>Web Design in Bournemouth</strike>
3. An image of a responsive website on a mobile phone

   - Yes: Example of a responsive website being displayed on a mobile phone
   - <strike>No: Responsive Website Design</strike>

You can find more examples on my blog post that I did earlier today, its still in draft and needs some grammar corrections but here you go.

> [SOURCE](https://www.bybe.net/bad-and-great-examples-of-image-alt-attributes/)
>
> Webmasters no longer need to fear about their keywords appearing at
>   the front of the alt, at the end of the alt or even not appearing at
>   all. Search engines can establish the contents and value of the page
>   with many other elements such as: `<title>`, `<meta>`, `<h1>` and `<p>`, in
>   fact Google and Bing can make sense of content with little or no
>   markup, HTML markup just helps them understand a little easier but in
>   no way is it absolutely required.
>
> Sadly, it is the year 2017 and we are still seeing SEO guides
>   mentioning things like the importance of keywords in Alt tags, key
>   word density, headers and so forth, all these things that really
>   mattered, no longer matter as much at all. You only need to take a
>   good look at Pro Webmasters, excellent rankings… which is filled with
>   thousands of pages with less than 90% of them having any images at all
>   and with hardly any HTML optimisation within the user generated
>   content areas of these pages.
>
> Good usage of the ALT attribute is composing the image ALT value that
>   consists of a short description that informs users the context of the
>   image. Sometimes describing less is often more and other times more is
>   more! Your descriptions should contain the elements of the image that
>   you want them to visualise, it is not for telling Google to rank THIS
>   because of this KEYWORD. Treat the ALT tag as a solution for partially
>   impaired, completely impaired or for users that have disabled images
>   in their browsers.